# In HandsomeSoup, how do I select the inner html of an element?

Tags: html, css, haskell

Say the html I'm parsing consists of the anchor tag:

```
<a href="/here">this is what I want</a>
```

Using the example in the package documentation I can get the href string "/here" by:

```
links <- runX $ doc >>> Text.HandsomeSoup.css "a" ! "href"
```

But how do I get the inner html? The following is in the spirit of what I'm looking for but does not work:

```
links <- runX $ doc >>> Text.HandsomeSoup.css "a" ! "value"
```

I have looked through the HandsomeSoup documentation thoroughly and at this point am wondering if this is even possible. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HandsomeSoup builds on top of hxt, and so you can use the (*vast*) API of hxt as well. More specifically, I believe that...

```
getChildren >>> isText >>> getText
```

... will extract the text contents from the elements. Here are the documentation entries for
[`getChildren`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.15/docs/Control-Arrow-ArrowTree.html#v:getChildren), [`isText`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.15/docs/Text-XML-HXT-Arrow-XmlArrow.html#v:isText) and [`getText`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.15/docs/Text-XML-HXT-Arrow-XmlArrow.html#v:getText). I suspect you'll also want something like [`hasAttrValue`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.15/docs/Text-XML-HXT-Arrow-XmlArrow.html#v:hasAttr) to better specify which anchors you are interested in.

Comment: links <- runX $ doc >>> Text.HandsomeSoup.css "a" >>> getChildren >>> isText >>> getText; That worked! Thank you!